# C# DownloadFileAsync does not download the file

Tags: c#, webclient

Usually I program in Java, but wanted to get away from it. So I tabbed into C#. While i noticed that many things are quiet simmilar, some are not (obviously).

To get to my problem:

The Program im writing basicaly downloads videofiles and saves them to a Directory specified by the User. So to achieve this I looked here on Stackoverflow and immidietly saw the solution.

```
WebClient.DownloadFileAsync(videoUri, saveDir);
```

So I went and added some code here and there and i came up with this:

```
private void btn_download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(saveDir + a.HoleTitel());
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        Uri video;
        try
        {
            videoUri = new Uri(a.HoleVideoURL());
            Console.WriteLine("Video has been defined! " + a.HoleVideoURL());
        } catch
        {
            videoUri = null;
            Console.WriteLine("Video is still null! NullPointerException incomming?");
        }
        webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
        webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
        webClient.DownloadFileAsync(videoUri, saveDir + a.HoleTitel() + "\\Episode " + a.HoleEpisode() + ".mp4");
    }

public void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            prozess.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }

        public void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Compleated!");
        }
```

When I enter the Url all seems to work flawlessly. When I press the Button, it creates the Directory and Episode 1.mp4 file and prints

> Video has been defined!

But it also shows a MessageBox, saiing "Compleated!" After a short while it prints this:

> Der Thread 0x7e0 hat mit Code 0 (0x0) geendet. -> "The Thread 0x7e0 has stoped with Code 0 (0x0)."

In theory this should download the file. But it doesn't do that. The file stays at 0 Bytes and there is no network activity.
Do you know how I can get it to work?

Comment: `Do you know how I can get it to work?` of course, if we knew what didn't work

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Please describe the problem more detailed and state the exact issue.

Comment: Sorry. I totaly forgot °~°. It doesnt download the file at all. Also there is no network activity. I edited the question ^^

Comment: What is `prozess`? Is this a UI element? This might cause a problem. To to comment this line out.

Comment: Yes. "prozess" is the progressBar on the UI. I started out coding this program in german but quickly felt uncomfortable with it and i forgot to change it. And commenting it out does not fix it :/

Comment: @akaruikage How to create a copy/paste ready example for us? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: In your `Completed` event handler, check if `e.Cancelled == true` before anything else. From what I see, the supplied URI is not valid, unreachable or forbidden. Also check `e.Error` to see what's what.

Comment: If it only says "Video has been defined!", it seems your a.HoleVideoURL() returns an empty string?

Comment: A method ending in Async usually needs to use 'await'

Comment: @HansKesting Yes, but not in this case.

Comment: @Hans Kesting  `DownloadFileAsync()` does not return a `Task`, it's a `void` method. It uses ThreadPool resources calling `WebRequest.BeginGetResponse()` setting an async Callback. [.NET Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/webclient.cs,2082).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DownloadFileAsync() call is probably fine. But notice that you have added a nice debug printout in the form of `Console.WriteLine("Video has been defined! " + a.HoleVideoURL());`

The output you get is

> Video has been defined!

This tells you that a.HoleVideoURL() does not give you any URL. And therefore the download is completed immediately, with an empty file as result.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I didn't noticed that. I checked back on this and now it is giving me this: "Video has been defined! http://s52.stream.proxer.me/files/3/7fzuxlqxkifnft/video.mp4"

Comment: The a.HoleVideoURL() doens't return a null string, but it returns the correct URL but with a excess " at the end....